# Issue while reloading jqgrid with scroll:true, initiates multiple ajax calls to load data

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid on my page which loads the first page of data while initializing. The scroll appears if there are more pages.

Problem is, if i scroll downs to see the second page and then trigger *reloadGrid* with updated url, it instantiates two ajax calls, with different page number (1 then 2).

In a result, grid is loaded with duplicate data returned against each call.

The above problem didn't appear if i didn't scroll down on first load.

**jqGrid Creation Code:**

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({ 
    url: 'test.do',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['', 'Item No.', 'HS Code', 'Goods Description', 'Quantity', 'Value', ''], 
    colModel: [{name:'itemId',       index:'itemId',       hidden:true},
               {name:'itemNo',       index:'itemNo',       width:100, align:'center', sortable:false}, 
               {name:'hsCode',       index:'hsCode',       width:100, align:'center', sortable:false}, 
               {name:'goodsDesc',    index:'goodsDesc',    width:350, align:'left',   sortable:false},
               {name:'itemQuantity', index:'itemQuantity', width:110, align:'right',  sortable:false},
               {name:'itemValue',    index:'itemValue',    width:110, align:'right',  sortable:false},
               {name:'action',       index:'action',       width:60,  align:'center', sortable:false}],
    width: 1000,
    height: 230,
    rowNum: 10,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    viewrecords: true,
    emptyrecords: "No Record Found.",
    multiselect: false, 
    scroll: true,
    jsonReader: {repeatitems:false, id:"0"}
});
```

**Code for reloading grid with new URL:**

```
newURL = 'test.do?itemNo=3';
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:newURL,datatype:'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
```

**AJAX calls after reload:**

```
http://abc.com/test.do?itemNo=3&page=1
http://abc.com/test.do?itemNo=3&page=2
```

Any body have any idea why it is happening??

Comment: In "jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:newURL,datatype:'json'}).trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);" remove [{page:1}] and use just reloadGrid. I think this will work.

Comment: i have tried by removing `[{page:1}]` from `trigger("‌​reloadGrid",[{page:1}])` but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following parameters in jqgrid creation script and it resolved the above issue:

set parameter `scroll:1` instead of `scroll:true`
then add new parameter `prmNames:{npage:1}`

Reference: [jqGridWiki:options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) in section: *prmNames, scroll*

Comment: This solved my issue to reset the current page after scrolling down to page 2+ and applying a search filter. Thanks!